# Can't Connect to MySQL via SSL (Unable to find valid certification path to requested target)

Tags: java, mysql, ssl

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL instance listening at `luther:3306`. I followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssl-tls-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04) on how to set up SSL for a MySQL instance on Ubuntu and it works great. I can connect to `luther:3306` with user `ford` no problem from the GUI (MySQL Workbench) when I provide it username, password, SSL key, SSL certificate, and SSL CA.

Now, I'm trying to connect via a Java app and I'm having issues giving Java the correct certificate. Here's the code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "SSL");

// Create the DB connection
try {
  String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://luther/ford";
  Properties dbProps = new Properties();
  dbProps.setProperty("user", "ford");
  dbProps.setProperty("password", "<password>");
  dbProps.setProperty("useSSL", "true");
  dbProps.setProperty("requreSSL", "true");

  dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, dbProps);
  log.info("Connected to DB? " + dbConnection.isValid(5000));
} catch (SQLException e) {
  log.fatal("Unable to connect to DB!");
  e.printStackTrace();
  return;
}
```

Here's the contents of the CA cert file:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin>keytool -keystore cacerts -list
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

mysqlcacert, Jan 20, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 71:92:DA:13:02:57:64:49:3D:72:A0:40:1B:B8:55:42:7D:21:0A:CF
mysqlclientcert, Jan 20, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): A1:F5:5A:DB:31:78:D9:3C:F7:D7:C6:28:77:AB:DF:0A:58:CC:EA:A7
```

It shows that I have my CA cert and my Client cert. Here's the top level exception I get when I run my Java program:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
```

Do I also somehow need to add my CA key or my client key to the keystore?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm assuming you have already created the keys by following these instructions:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html

And I'm assuming you've correctly configured the server using these instructions:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-encrypted-connections.html

(for those having trouble generating keys,  you can use CYGWIN for windows, and download OpenSSL as a package)

Now, for you specifically: There's no need to mess with the CACerts from the java keystore (bad practice). Instead use the following parameters at the end of the java connection string:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

```
...?useSSL=true&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file://path_to_truststore_file&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=mypassword
```

Also, make sure you import the certificates correctly. I myself followed these instructions after much research (I imported them into a separate keystore as recommended by the instructions)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

This got me connected. I'm running into other issues now, but this should fix your problem.

**EDIT:**
I also had to add the following:

```
trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file://path_to_truststore_file&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=mypassword
```